# Warning for nested links

Tags: reactjs

I have a `CardActionArea` component with a `Menu` component nested. So I want the user to be able to click the `Card` header and also open a pop up `Menu` to take some action. However, I get the following warning. How do I get around this? What's the appropriate way to resolve this?

```
index.js:1 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <button> cannot appear as a descendant of <button>.
```

```
<CardActionArea onClick={(e) => handleRedirect(e, k._id)}>

  <BlogGridMenu key={i} index={i} anchor={anchorEl} />

  <CardHeader
     avatar={}
     action={
       <IconButton id={i} aria-label="settings" onClick={handleMenuClick}>
          <MoreVertIcon />
       </IconButton>
     }
     title={k.title}
     subheader={getTimestamp(k._id)}
   />
  </CardActionArea>
```